# How to create a task to update parent's attribute based on last child's date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, task

I'm trying to build a web application for a small clinic, and I'm stuck.

I'm using:

- Ruby 2.6.5
- Rails 6.0.2
- The 'whenever' gem to run the task once a week.
- The 'simple_enum' gem to create the `:status` enum for the Pacient.

I'm trying to create a task to set the pacient's status based on the date of the last appointment.

If the Pacient doesn't schedule appointments for longer than six months, then the status would change to inactive. I'm doing this so I can show the list of inactives so the user can reach them and contact, something like this:

- if the last pacient's appointment was 6 months ago, set the status to inactive.
- if it was less than 6 months, set to active.
- I want to exclude the search if the Pacient.appointments is nil, because I'm already setting the pending in the after_create in the model.

I already tried something like this in the console to see if I would get somewhere:

```
Pacient.find_each do |pacient|
  pacient.appointments.order(:appointment_date).last
end
```

and I got the last appointment based on the date, but I haven't been able to write the code to actually change the status.

The parent model:

```
#app/models/pacient.rb

class Pacient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  as_enum :status, [:active, :inactive, :pending], pluralize_scopes: false
  after_create :set_pacient_status

  def set_pacient_status
    pending!
  end

end
```

The child model:

```
#app/models/appointment.rb

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pacient
  validates_presence_of %w[appointment_date pacient]
end
```

The Whenever schedule:

```
#config/schedule.rb

every 1.week do
  rake 'pacients:set_status'
end
```

The rake:

```
#lib/tasks/pacients.rake

namespace :pacients do
  desc 'set pacient status based on appointment_date'
  task set_status: :environment do
    #code here
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! By "pacients" do you mean "patients"? While it might not be obvious, spelling is important when coding; If you accidentally spell a variable or class differently than they're defined initially, your code won't work, but possibly worse, you'll probably get called out in a code-review by your peers, which is NEVER fun. Even worse would be reviewing code with a paying customer and find you'd misspelled their company name or product repeatedly. Every experienced programmer has been through the bug-chase just to find they'd misspelled something.

Comment: @theTinMan or its semi-english code. Not sure if thats better.

Comment: Thank you @theTinMan, the "c" in Patients was an honest mistake, not intentional. I'm Brazilian and we spell with a "c", so i got carried away when creating the model. I have already changed, again Thanks!

Comment: It's a weird situation dealing with code these days. It used to be that 99% of the code was English-based but as more and more collaboration occurs via team-programming and from around the world, it's becoming more important to standardize within teams especially, and with code-bases that are shared, such as GitHub. I don't believe in English-only in my personal life, but I can definitely see why it's important in code. Ah, the problems of the modern times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if an appointment `exists?` within six months, then update pacient's status:

```
Pacient.find_each do |pacient|
  pacient.update_column(:status,pacient.appointments.where('appointment_date > ?',6.months.ago).exists? ? 'active' : 'inactive')
end
```

Comment: great! glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `simple_enum` gem. `ActiveRecord::Enum` has been built into the framework since at least Rails 4. Use it instead of adding a superfluous dependency.

```
class Pacient < ApplicationRecord
  # This is built into rails
  enum status: {
    active: 0, 
    inactive: 1, 
    pending: 2
  }
  has_many :appointments
  after_create :set_pacient_status

  def set_pacient_status
    pending!
  end
end
```

To update all the users that have had a appointment in the last six months you would do:

```
# update all users with an appointment in the last 6 months
Pacient.joins(:appointments)
       .group('pacients.id')
       .where(
         appointments: { appointment_date: Float::INFINITY..6.months.ago }
       )
       .update_all(status: :active)
```

This does a single update query and will perform far better than pulling all the records out of the DB and doing N number of update queries.

The inverse query can be written as:

```
# update all users without an appointment in the last 6 months
Pacient.left_joins(:appointments)
       .group('pacients.id')
       .where(
         appointments: { appointment_date: Float::INFINITY..6.months.ago },
         id: nil
       )
       .update_all(status: :inactive)
```

Comment: when i run rails pacients:set_status i get the error: rails aborted! ArgumentError: bad value for range

Comment: By the way, thank you for the tip on enumeration. I have already changed it on the code!

Comment: Thats strange, what version of Ruby and Rails? You can also do lt/gt with a string condition `where('appointments.appointment_date <', 6.months.ago)` or [Arel](https://devhints.io/arel).

Comment: HI there, i'm using Ruby 2.6.5 and Rails 6.0.2. writing the where('appointments.appointment_date < ?', 6.months.ago) like this made it work, thank you!